# VBA textBox columns

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, shapes

How can I set columns number for the textbox in VBA for Excel? (excel located -> format shape -> text box -> columns). I have tried to look all over internet and office help but i can find only read only property column on the text box. I use Office 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recorded a macro, and it came up with this:

```
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 1")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.Column.Number = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

After a cut-n-paste from a Word doc, I found I had a text box called "Text Box 1". One line *(demo for the immediate window)* shows the number of columns :
`? Sheets(1).Shapes("Text Box 1").TextFrame2.Column.Number`

and FWIW the text in the box is :
`? Sheets(1).Shapes("Text Box 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text`